# Should I add @Transactional(readOnly = true) on custom methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's suppose I have the following repository:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Integer> {

    public boolean existsByCode(String code);

    public Optional<Application> findByCode(String code);

}
```

And the following service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationService {

    private final ApplicationRepository appRepo;

    public Application findById(Integer id) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        return appRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RecordNotFoundException("Application with id: " + id + " could not be found"));
    }

    public boolean existsByCode(String code) {
        return appRepo.existsByCode(code);
    }

    public Application findByCode(String code) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        return appRepo.findByCode(code).orElseThrow(
                () -> new RecordNotFoundException("Application with code: " + code + " could not be found"));
    }

}
```

1. Since default repository methods have @Transactional(readOnly = true), should I add the annotation on my custom methods? If so it's better to add the annotation on service methods or repository's?
2. If I have a third method, which call 2 other methods marked with @Transactional(readOnly = true), is it better to mark also this method with the annotation?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- Both questions cannot be answered definitively. It depends on the transaction boundaries, i.e. what should be part of the transaction. This is especially true for the 2nd question.

Comment: What makes you say that "default repository methods have `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`? I don't see any such annotation in the [source code of JpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.java) or its supertypes?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't pay much attention to `readOnly = true`. From Spring/Hibernate perspective specifying that causes following behaviour:

`JpaTransactionManager#doBegin` calls `HibernateJpaDialect#beginTransaction`, which in turn triggers following code:

```
if (definition.isReadOnly()) {
   session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
}
```

and `Session#setDefaultReadOnly` has following javadoc:

> Change the default for entities and proxies loaded into this session
> from modifiable to read-only mode, or from modifiable to read-only
> mode. Read-only entities are not dirty-checked and snapshots of
> persistent state are not maintained. Read-only entities can be
> modified, but changes are not persisted. When a proxy is initialized,
> the loaded entity will have the same read-only/modifiable setting as
> the uninitialized proxy has, regardless of the session's current
> setting.

So, `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` definition may save you some memory and CPU cycles (***it does not prevent HBN from modifying data in DB***), however in order to get some benefits from that the most outer transaction definition must be declared as readonly.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring reference manual [writes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings):

> The `@Transactional` annotation is metadata that specifies that an interface, class, or method must have transactional semantics (for example, "start a brand new read-only transaction when this method is invoked, suspending any existing transaction"). The default @Transactional settings are as follows:
>
> - The propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.
> - The isolation level is ISOLATION_DEFAULT.
> - The transaction is read-write.
> - The transaction timeout defaults to the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or to none if timeouts are not supported.
> - Any RuntimeException or Error triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

and the JavaDoc of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` says:

> Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists.

That is, if `@Transactional` service calls one or more `@Transactional` repositories, the service will manage the transaction, i.e. the transaction will begin upon entering the service method, and commit or rollback upon leaving it. The `@Transactional` on the repositories will detect the existing transaction, and do nothing, causing the repositories to participate in the existing transaction.

Starting a transaction in the service level is generally desirable. For one, having a single transaction means that all data is read in a single transaction, giving you stronger consistency guarantees than data loaded in separate transactions (between which another transaction might have modified the data). For another, starting a transaction has a cost, particularly with JPA, where each transaction has its own persistence context. That's why the hibernate team [speaks out](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_transactional_patterns_and_anti_patterns) against the "Session-per-operation anti-pattern".

Comment: I bet "hibernate team" still have not decided what is anti-pattern and what is not: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/

Comment: Well, you're betting wrong, because the hibernate team has consistently spoken out against both the Session-per-operation anti-pattern and the open-session-in-view antipattern, and consistently recommended the session-per-request pattern. If you actually read the link I provided, you will see that the session per request pattern doesn't say that the session should be open in the view, so these recommendations are entirely consistent.

Comment: "The term request here relates to the concept of a system that reacts to a series of requests from a client/user. Web applications are a prime example of this type of system, though certainly not the only one" - that is exactly what OSIV was implementing, and I'm not alone in this opinion: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view: "Session per request is a transactional pattern to tie the persistence session and request life-cycles together. Not surprisingly, Spring comes with its own implementation of this pattern, named OpenSessionInViewInterceptor"

Comment: The sentence you quote from the official docs only defines what a session is, it doesn't define the session per request pattern, about which the docs say that "At the beginning of handling such a request, the application opens a Hibernate Session, starts a transaction, performs all data related work, ends the transaction and closes the Session. The crux of the pattern is the one-to-one relationship between the transaction and the Session". Arguably, serialising a view is not "data related work", so it's entirely ok to close the session before that ...

Comment: and indeed, the hibernate docs go on to describe a variety of ways to accomplish that, including "a javax.servlet.Filter implementation", an "AOP interceptor with a pointcut on the service methods". `@Transactional` being an AOP interceptor, it's  quite clear that it should be on the service layer. I agree it's bad form of the hibernate team that their docs cite a servlet filter as an alternative, while prominent team members argue against that strategy, but it seems irrelevant to this question, which is about `@Transactional`.

Comment: if the main point in HBN docs was about http request defines transaction boundaries, it is even worse than "OSIV anti-pattern" - there are too many cons of doing that: once you have started transaction in NBH you have no option (or it is to complex) to start reading data from replica, you are holding DB connection while enriching data, unrelated exceptions in buggy code rollbacks transaction, etc. In general, business operation should define transaction boundaries, sometimes those boundaries coincide with http request, but in the most times they don't.

Comment: Hm ... if "business operations should define transaction boundaries" doesn't that mean that `@Transactional` should be on business services, just like my answer describes? You have however convinced me that the session per request part of the manual isn't good enough to be referenced in my answer, and I have therefore removed that reference. (I am keeping the reference to the session per operation antipattern to strengthen my argument that `@Transactional` should not be on repositories).

Comment: yeap, actually, I share more extreme ideas like https://stackoverflow.com/a/73605252/3426309